# adding less than and greater than characters to a string in asp vbscript

Tags: string, asp-classic, vbscript, special-characters

How does one add these characters " < > " to a string in asp vbscript?  Every time i have them in my string the string comes out blank.

```
mystring = "<some text>"
output :
```

Ive tried a few things and have searched around with no luck.  I am new to this language and not sure if i need some little hack to get this to output correctly.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just have `mystring = Server.HTMLEncode("<some text>")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mystring = "&lt;some text&gt;"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the code replacements for < (`&lt;`) and > (`&gt;`), which should work.

Comment: I cant up vote cuz my lack of reputation, but i definitely would.  Thank you!